# Publish events to Facebook with API V2

Tags: php, facebook, api, eventbrite

With Facebook API V1 it was possible to publish event. With API V2 this is not possible anymore.
But Eventbrite still has this function. 
How do they do it?

Comment: I checked Facebook login pages where you have to grant privileges to the app - mine is V2 and Eventbrite's is still V1. Looks like Facebook is doing V2 forced rollout in phases or is treating Eventbrite preferentially.

Comment: Yes, according to Facebook, the process of switching all apps over to API v2 is expected to take a couple of weeks. But no 3rd party app will get any special treatment – so even Eventbrite will not be able to create events via API any more, once their app is migrated to v2 as well.

Comment: @CBroe: this should be an answer, i´d be happy to upvote :)

Comment: @luschn: Done, plus a little extra explanation.

Comment: upvote done - didn´t want to steal the precious points :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Looks like Facebook is doing V2 forced rollout in phases

Yes, according to Facebook, the process of switching all apps over to API v2 is expected to take a couple of weeks. This was stated in the Facebook Developers Group on Facebook, when they started the v1 to v2 migration.

> or is treating Eventbrite preferentially.

No 3rd party app will get any special treatment – so even Eventbrite will not be able to create events via API any more, once their app is migrated to v2 as well.

This has also been stated by Facebook employees in the aforementioned group on multiple occasions. This topic has come up there frequently, also regarding f.e. removal of the ability to see all of a user’s friends or removal of the permission to access a user’s groups. People have been asking how “big players” like f.e. Hootsuite can still do those things, whereas their own apps that have been using API v2 already couldn’t – and the official answer has always been, those other apps are still using v1, but once they are migrated to v2 too, they will lose those abilities too, and there will be no special treatment or exceptions.

Comment: Anyone knows the official reason for disabling adding events while still keeping enabled adding posts?

Answer (score 3):

**They are receiving special treatment from Facebook** and they are using current API versions (or very near, 2.5 instead of 2.6 as of June 2016).

They keep repeating that statement ad infinitum: "No 3rd party app will get any special treatment" but it's simply not true.  EventBrite is using v2.5 and V1 was phased out April last year?

You can definitely still publish facebook events directly from within EventBrite.

> Facebook has a long standing record of setting double standards with regards to their API, regardless of what Zuckerberg might preach at F8 from his podium.

[image]

Comment: I tried it out and they really allow publishing of events. Although they now limit this option to pages. Have you tried publishing event to a page recently?

Comment: Thanks, we will try it again.  What API version did you try it with?

Comment: I was probably not clear enough - I tried publishing event on Eventbrite not through API

Comment: Yeah, I know EventBrite works.  The problem is they're the only ones allowed to do it.  Facebook hath bestowed upon them a very special honor.

Answer (score 0):

I got this response from Facebook - have not yet tried if this really works:

*Thank you for writing to us. We understand your reaction however please do try out sample permissions using Graph API and you would be able to understand which permission is producing the dialog you see with Everbrite.

For example the dialog you see as per stack overflow report is using the rsvp_event login permission that is available to all our developers.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/ -> rsvp_event section will help you understand how you can request for one and what actions can be performed in terms of "managing your event"*

Comment: We're you able to act on this? I don't really understand what this means.

Comment: Don't bother trying.  From the docs "This permission does not let you create an event. There is no way to create an event through the API." https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-rsvp_event