# Creating Facebook event for page using PHP SDK 5

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am looking for a straight and up to date answer on this. There are a lot of guides and answers on using older versions of the php sdk and the graph api, but nothing current.
**So,any one know how to create an event on a page using the Facebook php sdk 5.0?**

Comment: I found this question. Is the answer still applicable to today? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30146042/publish-events-to-facebook-with-api-v2

Comment: You need to show us you've put in some effort to figure this out yourself. What have you tried? What guides or answers have you followed, and where did they fail?

Comment: Do you want to see my browser history or something? Not trying to be rude, but how do I prove that I haven't found an answer before asking this question?

Comment: If you really want to know what I have tried, I have downloaded the sdk and looked through the documentation for how to publish events. The documents say there is no end point for publishing events. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/events/ However, I found guides that show how to publish events, but they are all old and use an older sdk. Nothing current. Then I found the q/a above and I am a bit confused. So I am looking a straight yes/no answer and maybe some current guidance if the answer is yes.